# Project is not found in sourceforge search. How do I resolve this?

Tags: search, sourceforge

Project name : SQLiteWrapper
URL: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitewrap/

Hi,

I created the project on 3 Dec 2010. I type in the project name in the search edit box on the sourceforge home page, however the project is not returned or found.
Can you please advise as to why this is happening and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reply from sourceforge:

.....
 There was an issue with our search results updater. We are working on
 fixing this and your project is now visible.
.....